# $scope.message not able to display text value

Tags: angularjs

I created an empty MVC5 web application and trying to display a message in the view which is returned from the external javascript file.

```
 @{
  ViewBag.Title = "Index";
  Layout = null;
  }

<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/myscript.js"></script>
<title>My AngularJS Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="myController">
{{ message }}
</div>
<div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have created my angularjs code in external js file and referenced it in my view.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myModule', []);

var myController = function($scope)
{
$scope.message = "Hello from AngularJS";
}

myApp.controller("myController", myController);
```

Instead of displaying "Hello from AngularJS" its just displaying {{ message }} , any clue on what i am missing here ?

Comment: You're using ng-app="myApp", but your module is named myModule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-app="myApp"` is wrong. your module name is `myModule`. then you should replace it to `ng-app="myModule"`.